# Kivy app build by buildozer crash every time on android

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I would like to ask for help since everything I found online or try myself either doesnt work or I have no idea what am I doing. At this point I have main and kv file that looks like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        try:
            picture_size = self.ids.main_grid.children[2].size[1]
            rect_size_x, rect_size_y = self.ids.main_grid.children[0].size[0],   self.ids.main_grid.children[0].size[1]
            multiplication = int(len(self.ids.main_grid.children)/4)
            scroll_height = multiplication*picture_size + multiplication*rect_size_y

            self.ids.main_grid.height = scroll_height

            size_ = (100,20)
            step = picture_size + rect_size_y
            pos_x, pos_y = 0, (rect_size_y - size_[1])/2 
            with self.ids.main_grid.canvas:
                
                for i in range(multiplication):
                    Color(rgb=(.6,.8,.2))
                    pos_x = (rect_size_x - size_[0])/2
                    self.rect = Rectangle(size=size_, pos=(pos_x, pos_y))
                    
                    pos_x = (rect_size_x - size_[0])/2 + rect_size_x
                    self.rect2 = Rectangle(size=size_, pos=(pos_x, pos_y))

                    Color(rgb=(.55,.6,.65))
                    self.line = Line(rectangle=self.rect.pos + self.rect.size, width = 2)
                    self.line = Line(rectangle=self.rect2.pos + self.rect2.size, width = 2)

                    pos_y += step
        except:
            pass

    pass

class Trenink(App):
    def build(self):
        
        sm = ScreenManager()
        menu_screen = MenuScreen()
        sm.add_widget(menu_screen)
        return sm
trenink = Trenink()
trenink.run()
```

```
<MenuScreen>:
    name: "menu"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: 400, 800
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 30
            padding: 20, 10, 20, 10
            size_hint: None, .08
            size: root.width, root.height/30
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.2,.2, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Button:
                text: "Celkove info"
                font_size: 16
            Button:
                text: "Cile"
                font_size: 16
            Button:
                text: "Seznam cviku"
                font_size: 16
        GridLayout:
            id: main_grid
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: 2500
            cols: 2
            rows: 12
            Button:
                text: "B1"
                background_color: 0, .6, 1, 1
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 200
            Button:
                text: "B2"
                background_color: 0, .6, 1, 1
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 200
            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 50
                text: "Progres bar1"
            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 50
                text: "Progres bar2"
            Button:
                text: "B3"
                background_color: 0, .6, 1, 1
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 200
            Button:
                text: "B4"
                background_color: 0, .6, 1, 1
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 200
            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 50
                text: "Progres bar3"
            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 50
                text: "Progres bar4"
```

The code doesnt have any functionality as I had to reduce it to a minimum to find a mistake (which I didnt find). So I used the buildozer, where I tried to type all possible requirements, that I saw online might be important:
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,pillow,kivy.uix.boxlayout,kivy.app,kivy.uix.scrollview,kivy.uix.screenmanager,kivy.graphics,kivy.uix.boxlayout,kivy.uix.gridlayout,kivy.uix.button,kivy.uix.label

After making an app and installing it on android, it crash. Tried using adb logcat too but unfortunatelly dont know what to look for in that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, there's no need of a pass keyword when you have stuff going inside the class remove the pass keyword, i dont know why are you using a try except, in the sense as to what you want to achieve using try and except, but you can use that, further, it's better if you post error log, and also try it without the pass keyword, i believe that should do the work

Comment: Also your requirements are unnecessary, you don't need to specify anything except this `requirements = python3, kivy, pillow`